# Crystal Reports in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I know the use of server-side controls is a no-no in ASP.NET MVC, however we have a long list of crystal reports that the company has already produced for a previous application that I would like to utilize for our new ASP.NET MVC application.

Is there an appropriate way to use crystal reports in ASP.NET MVC?  If so, how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We had/have a similar situation at work.

The solution we use:

- Create a seperate directory for reports
- Create normal ASPX pages for reports

We have not seen any issues (besides the normal Crystal ones) with this setup.

Comment: How do you exclude the directory from the routes?

Comment: Actually, I just checked. No need to modify the route.

Comment: If you added a Crystal report in asp.net MVC then have you encountered problem of Refreshing Crystal report?

Have you faced  "Validation of viewstate MAC failed error" ?

Comment: You'll have to deal with authorization somehow with this approach.

Comment: @Vikas are you using that "CrystalReportSource" thing? If so use ReportDocument and save you report document and maybe it will be better

Comment: @leppie can you please add more details and help me how to pass multiple parameters from MVC view to webform and print crystal reports , please check my question and help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498523/how-to-transfer-this-code-from-asp-net-to-asp-net-mvc-to-print-crystal-reports?noredirect=1#comment110528249_62498523

Answer (score 76):

It is pretty simple actually. just add following references to your MVC project:

- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
- CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
- CrystalDecisions.Shared

use Action method like below:

- C# :

  ```
  using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

  public ActionResult Report()
      {
          ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
          rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("[reportName].rpt");
          rptH.Load();
          rptH.SetDataSource([datatable]);
          Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
          return File(stream, "application/pdf");   
      }
  ```
- VB.NET :

  ```
   Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

   Public Function Report() As ActionResult
      Dim rptH As New ReportClass()
      rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("[reportName].rpt")
      rptH.Load()
      rptH.SetDataSource([datatable])
      Dim stream As IO.Stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
      Return File(stream, "application/pdf")
   End Function
  ```

Comment: Nice - very elegant (Crystal reports and elegant in the same conversation - cue end of the world)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294762/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010-error for further info that you might need. (I Did!)

Comment: Finally got around to implementing this. Coudlnt' have been easier, thanks!

Comment: thinking of moving back to crystal from rdlc

Comment: It worked fine but got 'database logon failed' when adding multiple tables with impersonate = true.

Comment: I have to send parameters to the crystal report how i will do it in MVC ?

Answer (score 2):

**Just add this reference :   using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

than do this action :**

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;  
    public ActionResult Report()
            {
                List<Table> table = new List<Table>();
                ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
                rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Repport/CrystalReport1.rpt")));

                Response.Buffer = false;
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);


                return File(stream, "application/pdf", "Suivie Historique.pdf");


            }
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.