# Crystal report not loading on published software

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i am trying to get my report viewer on winforms to load a crystal report file, when i test it on my visual studio it runs all fine, but once i publish it, it gives me this error

```
 See the end of this message for details on invoking
```

just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack.
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String

Below is my code used to load the report file

```
 ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;

        PayrollRep payrollrep = new PayrollRep();


        string myreportname = payrollrep.Name;

        cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\PayrollRep.rpt");
        ////cryRpt.Load("PayrollRep.rpt");

        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "xxxxx";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "xxxx";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "xxxx";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "xxxx";

        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

I am quite sure it has to do with the load directory, as it is not embedded but i don't know the proper way to set the path so that it finds the file after publish.

Answer (score 0):

try to install runtime on machine where you want to run your app.

[32 bit](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_16.zip)

[64 bit](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_16.zip)

Comment: i just found my solution on this other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833894/a-document-processed-by-the-jrc-engine-cannot-be-opened-in-the-c-stack

Comment: thank you anyway, i just had to put the built action of my report file to content