# A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack in c# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I know this question has been asked many times but none of those has solved my problem. I am new in windows application. I am showing some records in Crystal reports. Here is my code...

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
ds = new InstallationReport();
ds = PrintInstallationReport();
ds.Tables[0].Merge(ds.Tables[0]);
//string AppPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Reports\\InstallationReport.rpt";
//rptDoc.Load(AppPath);
                //rptDoc.Load(@"F:\vs10\Windows\RapidDiagnostic\RapidDiagnostic\Reports\InstallationReport.rpt");
rptDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports\\InstallationReport.rpt");
rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

It's working fine. But when I installed it to another computer it does not work and shows the following  error...

`Load Report Failed. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack`

I can understand, this error occurred when application does not find the desired report. But what is wrong with my code. Please help guys...

Comment: Does the other computer have access to \\reports\\installationreport.rpt? can you make your code point to c:\installationreport.rpt instead and see if that works better? Also, is the file already open by another computer?

Comment: @Sun You mean to say, I should put my reports to root folder not `reports` folder ? It works fine when I call the report direct by giving path like `@c:\installationreport.rpt`. But fails when I use `Application.Startup+"\\Reports\\InstallationReport.rpt"`

Comment: UNC path means the report is on the network. So, the new computer needs access to it. This is to test your code and eliminate the network path to isolate where your issue is coming from. Can you open the report from Windows Explorer from new workstation?

Comment: Yes it works fine when I use something like `c:\installationreport.rpt`

Comment: Well, you know then it is not your code. It has to do with the network path being inaccessible, or the file is already open/being used.

Comment: Is it any permission issue ? What should I do ?

Comment: Sorry I do not know. I think your question is too localized to determine. If and when you figure out your answer, please post your answer and mark it an answer.

Comment: @Sun I checked my Installation Destination Folder. When I installed this application. The destination folder (c:\Program Files\MyProjectName) does not contain any folder named `Report`. Can you help me please ?

Comment: You save application data to another directory in windows called AppData %AppData%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833894/a-document-processed-by-the-jrc-engine-cannot-be-opened-in-the-c-stack)