# Crystal report is not rendering in production environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

Crystal report viewer throws Runtime Error in hosting environment while it was working well with visual studio.

Exception image below here :
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: this is not exactly exception message. just change your custom error mode

Answer (score 1):

Set customerror mode to off in configuration file:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

then you would be able to see actual exception. Moreover you can check application log also.
Be careful,change customerror once problem is fixed otherwise it will expose sensitive information.

Comment: after doing thet i got this :- Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack

Comment: There can be multiple reason for this. plz refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833894/a-document-processed-by-the-jrc-engine-cannot-be-opened-in-the-c-stack