# ASP CrystalReportViewer will not display report

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

So here is the code

```
protected void GenerateReport()
{
    SalesOrder r1 = new SalesOrder();
    var path = Server.MapPath("App_Code/SalesOrder.rpt");
    r1.Load(path);
    r1.SetParameterValue("SONumber", 266305);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = r1;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

}
And declarative

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" 
    DisplayToolbar="False" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" ToolPanelView="None" />
```

The report was originally designed for WinForms application. 
I'm probably making some rookie mistake here.
The report authenticates well with SQL server and executes the query. I traced it in SQL profiler. I can safely assume that it receives result set (I executed the query captured to verify that). The report in preview shows well with the parameters. But when it goes to ASP and the browser, the contents of master page display well but report does not render in the viewer. What rookie mistake am I making here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was really loosing it and then I did it! Copy aspnet_client folder from anywhere you find it in inetpub into your ASP.NET application folder.