# Is there any way where i can using Crystal Report in ASP. NET MVC3 with Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crystal Reports in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348785/crystal-reports-in-asp-net-mvc)

Is there any way where i can use Crystal Report in ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor view engine. I have installed separately crystal report to my VS 2010, but i didnt see Reports tab in my vs2010 Tools.

Any help, I am so confused.

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348785/crystal-reports-in-asp-net-mvc