# How to route a .aspx page in asp.net mvc 3 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a .aspx page in the following path:

```
Areas/Management/Views/Ticket/Report.aspx
```

I want to route that to the following path in my browser:

```
http://localhost/Reports/Tickets
```

How can i do that?

I try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Tickets", // Route name
    "Areas/Management/Views/Ticket/Report.aspx", // Original URL
    new { controller = "Reports", action = "Tickets" } // New URL 
);
```

But i got the `404` error.

What i'm doing wrong?

Obs: I put that before the `Default` route.

Comment: Is your .aspx page, a web forms aspx page or an mvc webforms view engine page?

Comment: You can have .aspx views which use the web forms view engine, and you can have .aspx web forms. I suspect you are trying to get a hybrid of web forms and mvc to work, but it is unclear (to me at least) which you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to use a crystal reports in my asp.net mvc project. And i'm trying to use a ReportViewer that only works (with full features) in web forms. So, now i only want to route the .aspx page that has the ReportViewer as mvc views (without .aspx at the end of URL).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Solved!** So, we need to add a route contraint to the webforms route to ensure that it only catches on incoming routes, not outgoing route generation.

Add the following class to your project (either in a new file or the bottom of global.asax.cs):

```
public class MyCustomConstaint : IRouteConstraint{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection){
        return routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest;
    }
}
```

Then change the Tickets route to the following:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "Tickets",
    "Reports/Tickets",
    "~/WebForms/Reports/Tickets.aspx",
    true, null, 
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "outgoing", new MyCustomConstaint() } }
);
```

Comment: Thank you CodeHobo for this solution.  [Reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/1793416.aspx/1)

Comment: I'm Vecthor. @JabberwockyDecompiler

Comment: Hmm, not sure why I put that, did you change your name?

Comment: I made the same question there, so, with the answer of CodeHobo I put here. "I'm Vecthor" there. It is only a alias, codename, something like that ^^.

Comment: My friends call me Jabber :D, haha, actually I go by TJ.

Answer (score 22):

If you are trying to utilise web forms in a MVC project then I would move your .aspx out of the views folder, as it isn't really a view, so something like WebForms/Tickets/Report.aspx.

In web forms you map a route by calling the `MapPageRoute` method.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapPageRoute("Tickets", "Reports/Tickets", "~/WebForms/Tickets/Report.aspx");
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

You'll need to put that before the default MVC route.

Comment: When i run the project the browser redirect to the folling url "http://localhost:37538/Reports/Tickets?action=Index&controller=Login". Oo

Comment: It's matching the default route at a guess, the line above needs to be directly after the `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")` line

Comment: I put that directly after the `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")` and i got the same url. =/

Comment: I've just tried it in a new mvc project and that works fine for me. Are you putting `/Reports/Tickets` directly into your browser or clicking a link on another page?

Comment: I'm running the project, and the browser redirects to this url. Oo

Comment: Put in you project a forms auth i see if when you try to access the root page, it's redirected to this url (block in web.config all paths if the user is not logged).

Comment: I get redirected to `http://localhost/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f` - I suspect there is in either your routing or web.config that's causing this. Maybe try it in a clean MVC project. Also this answer may help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2747571/385149

Comment: I cannot to use as pdf only. I need to use the ReportViewer.

Comment: I debug the project, and i saw that after add the `MapPageRoute`, the project stops to enter in my `Home Controller`.

Comment: When you run the project you're aready logged in? If yes, try to log off and you will see (i test in a separeted project too).

Comment: No, if I was already logged in then i wouldn't get redirected to the Account/LogOn page.

Answer (score -1):

you are doing it opposite. this maps your url `Areas/Management/Views/Ticket/Report.aspx` to { `controller = "Reports", action = "Tickets" }`
what u should do instead is 
set the url as 
`Reports/Tickets` 
EDIT:- you can create a routeHandler just for routing to this .aspx page.. like this.

```
public class ASPXRouteHandler : IRouteHandler 
{ 
   public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) 
   { 

     return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/Areas/Management/Views/Ticket/Report.aspx",  typeof(Page)) as Page; 
   } 
}
```

then u can add ur route to the existing routes table using

```
Route customRoute = new Route("Reports/Ticket",null, new ASPXRouteHandler()); 
      routes.Add(customRoute);
```

Comment: If i put the `Reports/Tickets` how the site 'll route to my aspx page?

Comment: ull have to make a route handler.. currently ur url is getting mapped to Reports/Tickets which obsly dosent exists.. and hence ur getting 404. try returning a string from "Reports/Tickets" and ull see where u r wrong

Comment: Dude, i don't want to see that i'm wrong. "I'm wrong", ok, i know (it's because i'm here ^^), now i have to know how to solve my problem. =) A code, an exemple, a link...

Comment: What i have to put in `defaults`? And in `new CustomRouteHandler()` you want to mean `new ASPXRouteHandler()`, right?

Comment: When i run the project the browser redirect to the folling url "http://localhost:37538/Reports/Tickets?action=Index&controller=Login". Oo

Comment: do u have some kind of authentication in place.. like forms authentication?

Comment: k then if u can authticate and then url this Url - "Reports/TIcket" it would be awsm.. becuz ur authenticated then u wont be redirected to the login url or ull have to add the Url Reports/TIcket to unauthenticated access by using webconfigs location tag. search it.

Comment: Dude, i didn't understand what you said. What is "awsm"? And to you know, this page "Reports/TIcket" could only be access if the user is logged.

Answer (score -2):

if you leave the default routing when you create the asp.net project

```
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Ticket()
        {
            return View();
        }        
}
```

this should do the trick.
The routing in asp.net mvc means that you don't link directly to *.aspx but to Actions (methods) that in turn return an appropriate view (*.aspx)

Comment: But with this the url (when i return the .aspx page) will have the .aspx at the end, will not?

Comment: No it will not. Have you actually tested it, (voting me down)? I've actually corrected the code so it will return
http://localhost/Reports/Tickets

Comment: if you trying to use crystal reports then you should check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348785/crystal-reports-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I saw it. The page is working (i've tested in another project), my problem now is only route it in asp.net mvc project.

Comment: Is your problem really in MVC, from what I've gathered from your previous comments you have webform doing the display, so perhaps what you need is the IIS url rewrite module to take of this specific page. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/ or do you have a controller to handle the request before sending to your view?

Comment: I cannot use this. The prerequisite is "IIS 7 with ASP.NET role service enabled." and my IIS is 6. =/

Comment: How about this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx