# MVC getting id on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button

I am trying to get the id of the selected button.

This is my code below

```
 <% foreach (var item in Model.getLeagues) { %>
        <a href=Teams.aspx class="leagueImage">
            <img src="../../<%: item.image %>" alt="<%: item.name %>" />
            </a>
    <% } %>
```

With this code I am generating 5 buttons and then I need the id of the clicked button.

Any help of how I can get this id ?

Thanks

Comment: What language? Do you mean ASP.NET MVC? If so, use the more specific tag.

Comment: yes pls.. asp-net MVC... sorry bout tags

Comment: Increment an integer during the loop.  append the integer to a string to give the id that looks like this: id="blammoButton3"

Comment: I've added the ASP.NET MVC tag. You may also want to add a more specific tag if need be. Check the tags out. The better your tags, the better your chances of attracting the right experts to your problem. Best of luck!

Comment: The Id of the item or the index of the collection?

Comment: well I can add a loop with the id and read it from the method...but how can I read the ID of the selected <a> (button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the ID from the controller, why not take the suggestion Marko made, but instead of putting it into the id attribute, instead put make it part of your href tag and pass the ID attribute.

By default, the routing in MVC expects back an ID which is part of your route in:

```
http://sitename/{Controller}/{Action}/{Id}
```

So, you could do something like this (I'm going to use Razor syntax, but, you can adjust):

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.getLeagues.Count; i++) {
  Html.ActionLink("Button Name", "Index", "MyController", new { id = Model.getLeages[i] }, new { @class="classname", alt = "@Model.getLeagues[i].name" }) %>
}
```

And, in your controller (rename as appropriate) you would have:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
  public ActionResult Index(int id) {
    // Do stuff with the ID that you get back here.
  }
}
```

Also, you'll notice that I broke out your image information. Instead, make a class in your stylesheet like:

```
a.classname
{
    background: url(../Images/image.gif) no-repeat top left;
    /* Do whatever else you need to do here to style your buttons. */
}
```

I didn't check any of the code, so can't guarantee it's syntactically perfect, but that should get you going down a right path.

I did notice your path to Teams.aspx. If you are coming from WebForms, you can edit your routing file to direct towards the RESTful route like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Teams", "MyController/Index", "~/WebForms/Index/Teams.aspx");
```

(Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10175580/132528)

Comment: I upvoted your answer since your solution is much better than mine of course. The only reason I suggested a querystring is because he has an image nested within his anchor tag and Html.ActionLink will not be able to handle that. But even so he is still better off using href="/controllername/actionname/id"

Comment: @Marko - Thanks for the upvote. I see what you mean about the image - he picks based on something with the item, which, you're right, my CSS solution wouldn't work there. Good call.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your loop to following:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i <= Model.getLeagues.Count; i++) { %>
    <a href="Teams.aspx" id="link_<%: i %>" class="leagueImage">
        <img src="../../<%: Model.getLeagues[i].image %>" alt="<%: Model.getLeagues[i].name %>" />
        </a>
<% } %>
```

now you have anchor tags with unique IDs (link_0, link_1, ...). So now using jquery click event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".leagueImage").click(function() {
      alert($(this).id);
   });

});
```

will get you a popup box that will display the ID of the clicked anchor tag.

Comment: seems pretty good but how do I access the id from the controller please ?

Comment: Well if you want to access it from the controller you're going to have to pass it via querystring like this:

<a href="Teams.aspx?id=link_<%: i %>" id="link_<%: i %>" class="leagueImage">

Comment: ok and then access them like this right ?
public ActionResult Foo(string id) {...}

Comment: Of course the solution provided by @JasCav bellow is much better because it is written based on the MVC behavior and if you can, you should try to use it. It's much better to use MVC routing and Html.ActionLink helper than passing parameters via querystrings. However if you absolutely need to have an image within your anchor tag then you need to use what I said above or you need to write your own custom html helper that will handle that type of scenario..

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the index of the collection you are looping though, try this:

```
Model.getLeagues.indexOf(item)
```

Comment: I am trying to get the id of the selected item ex: loaded 5 buttons and chosen the 3rd one. how can I get the id = 3.