# ASP.NET MVC - disable browsing folders , allowing access to aspx files without specifying path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my ASP.NET MVC5 application, in root folder of myProject I've a folder "subfolder" that contains page.aspx . When I perform some action in my controller, it redirect to subfolder/page.aspx, but in the address bar of browser is shown "www.mysite.com/subfolder/page.aspx". My goal is to redirect to page.aspx without allowing navigation through folders and showing in address bar "www.mysite.com/page".
Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to route a .aspx page in asp.net mvc 3 project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175200/how-to-route-a-aspx-page-in-asp-net-mvc-3-project)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `MapPageRoute` to route to static files in the Route.config.

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    routeName: "aspx",
    routeUrl: "page",
    physicalFile: "~/Subfolder/page.aspx",
    checkPhysicalUrlAccess:false
);
```

Additionally if you want to disallow navigating to the physical url setup a deny in the web.config

```
<location path="Subfolder/page.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```