# MVC offers download file instead of opening it

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am having a problem with my MVC project. Instead of opening first page of my project it offers me to download that file. Basically it offers me to download login.aspx file. I can not open any other link of my project - it offers me to download that link instead of opening it.

I am using IIS express. I really don't understand why this is happening?

I am using VS 2017.

Photo of my settings:

[image]

Comment: Without knowing how you are serving your MVC application it's difficult to tell, but most ASP.NET MVC applications do not use the .aspx extension. You should rather be pointing to a specific action on a controller using a route.

Comment: YEs, it's true, that was aspx project at start. I've added MVC later. So it's combined now.

Comment: If this happened after adding MVC it sounds like it's only trying to serve routes and not .aspx files. You could try out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175200/how-to-route-a-aspx-page-in-asp-net-mvc-3-project

Comment: Could you please tell me how you combine the MVC application to your web form application? Do you create the new router for MVC? Do you have the route for your web form application? If possbile, please post some related codes.