# What is the best reporting tool for ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, report

I have been using ASP.NET MVC 3 for a while to implement a testing application. Now I am at a point where I need a reporting tool to see and compare percentages of performances of different people over a period of time using a line graph. Can anyone please suggest an efficient reporting tool which works great with MVC3 ... Thank you for the help.

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348785/crystal-reports-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server reporting service views and rdl file types are available right within an MVC3 project. They don't require a SSRS server and can be designed right within Visual Studio. Quickest and easiest solution.. and free.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow here, how is an SSRS 'view' available in MVC3?  Theres the rdlc files, which require the report viewer, which in turn is not mvc worthy by default.

Comment: All you do is add an .aspx page to the project, on that, drop the viewer control on and tie it up to an .rdl file. I've used it several times in an MVC app, the two work swimmingly side by side, you can call the aspx page from any MVC view

Comment: Sure, But that's not MVC anymore this is using webforms in MVC, which some folks despise doing especially I they've disable the webforms view engine too. Just wanted to clarify, this isn't an MVC view at all (in regards to reporting )it's webforms with MVC looking at it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I finally managed to do it by adding an '.aspx' page to hold report viewer, used SSRS server to create the report and finally to put the webform in my MVC 3 View I just used a simple <iframe> tag .. I required a bit of styling to position the report inside the '.cshtml' view