# javascript code for loading crystal report in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

My question is related to this link : 
[Crystal Reports in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348785/crystal-reports-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1)
As per one of teh answer by coderguy123
I have written Action method at controller side ? But what will be the 
javascript side code ( i will be using js file to invoke this Action method )

Also , return type of action method in following method is

```
public ActionResult Report()
{
    ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
    rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("[reportName].rpt");
    rptH.Load();
    rptH.SetDataSource([datatable]);
    Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
    return File(stream, "application/pdf");   
}
```

File .. but when i call it from js file , it is giving error .. Not sure if return type matched with datatype file ...

Basically , I want client side code to invoke this method and display the pdf file in new browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this and forgot to update this post . 
As a beginner I was assuming that this can be done through $.ajax .. 
Returning file stream can not be done through an ajax but through 
direct call like window.open from client side ..

window.open('/YourController/YourAction?')

You can open the stream in both pdf and html format ..